# How to use conditionals in an apex: repeat and place a custom link in a visualforce email template?

Tags: email-template, repeat, conditional, visualforce-template, custom-link

I am creating a visualforce email template that sends contact data to salespeople.

In this email there are two points that I am not able to advance:

1. In the section "Informações sobre o agendamento", I would like that the apex repeat that has below it to bring the start and end date information only if the subject of the event starts with "Agd:"
2. Below in "Tarefas Relacionadas" and "Compromissos relacionados" I needed the subject of each task or event to link to those tasks, but I don't know how to bring the link to custom shape.

Could someone please help me with these questions?

Below I leave all the email code for analysis :)

```
<messaging:emailTemplate subject="Novo agendamento!" recipientType="Contact" relatedToType="Contact">
<messaging:htmlEmailBody > 
    <html>
        <body>
        
            <table>
               <tr>
                   <p>Olá{!relatedto.Owner.FirstName}, tudo bem?</p>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                   <p>Você tem uma nova reunião agendada!</p>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                   <p>Confira abaixo tudo o que você precisa saber sobre seu lead e o agendamento!</p>
               </tr>
             </table>
            <table>
                 <tr>
                     <th>Informações sobre o agendamento</th>
                 </tr>
                 <apex:repeat rows="1" value="{!relatedTo.Events}" var="event">
               <tr>
                   <p><strong> Início: </strong>{!event.StartDateTime}</p>
                   <p><strong> Fim: </strong>{!event.EndDateTime}</p>
               </tr>
               </apex:repeat>
               <tr>
                   <p><strong>Nome da empresa:</strong> {!relatedto.Account.Name}</p>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                   <p><strong>Site:</strong> {!relatedto.Account.Website}</p>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                   <p><strong>Telefone:</strong> {!relatedto.Phone}</p>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                   <p><strong>Nome:</strong> {!relatedto.Name}</p>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                   <p><strong>Cargo:</strong> {!relatedto.Title}</p>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                   <p><strong>E-mail:</strong> {!relatedto.Email} </p>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                   <p><strong>Setor:</strong> {!relatedto.Account.Industry}</p>
               </tr>
           </table>
           <table>
               <tr>
                   <th>Tarefas Relacionadas</th>
               </tr>
               <apex:repeat rows="5" value="{!relatedTo.Tasks}" var="tarefa">
               <tr>
                   <td>
                       <p><strong> Assunto: </strong>{!tarefa.Subject}</p>
                   </td>
               </tr>  
               </apex:repeat>
           </table>
           <table>
               <tr>
                   <th>Compromissos relacionados</th>
               </tr>
               <apex:repeat rows="5" value="{!relatedTo.Events}" var="compromisso" >
               <tr>
                   <td>
                       <p><strong> Assunto: </strong>{!compromisso.Subject}</p>
                   </td>
               </tr>  
               </apex:repeat>
           </table>
        </body>
    </html>
</messaging:htmlEmailBody>
```

</messaging:emailTemplate>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The former is just a simple apex:outputText/rendered setup:

```
       <apex:repeat rows="1" value="{!relatedTo.Events}" var="event">
           <apex:outputText rendered="{!LEFT(event.Subject,4)='Agd.'}">
           <tr>
               <p><strong> Início: </strong>{!event.StartDateTime}</p>
               <p><strong> Fim: </strong>{!event.EndDateTime}</p>
           </tr>
           </apex:outputText>
       </apex:repeat>
```

For the latter, use an anchor tag (`<a>`):

```
           <apex:repeat rows="5" value="{!relatedTo.Tasks}" var="tarefa">
           <tr>
               <td>
                   <p><strong> Assunto: </strong>
                    <a href="{!URLFOR($Action.Task.View,tarefa.Id)}">{!tarefa.Subject}</a>
                   </p>
               </td>
           </tr>  
           </apex:repeat>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! The first code helped me to bring the right event, but the second one doesn't work so well :(
It gives an error because it's not linking yet to the right task. Do you know another condition that I can use? Or maybe some documentation showing all of them?

Comment: @LeticiaSilvaJordao What's the error?

Comment: A new page opens with the following message:

Redirect warning
  The page on which you were is trying to get you to an invalid url
(http:///00T2D000008hHjOUAU/d?retURL=%2Fp%2Femail%2Ftemplate%2FVfEmailTemplatePreview%3Fsetupid%3DCommunicationTemplatesEmail%26isdtp%3Dp1&_CONFIRMATIONTOKEN=VmpFPSxNakF5TVMwd05DMHhOMVF4TURvd016bzBNeTR3T0RoYSxLc2lBNXd2LTlwb05oSjM1N3dqWE9ILE5UWXhNalZq&common.udd.actions.ActionsUtilORIG_URI=%2F00T2D000008hHjOUAU%2Fd&isdtp=p1).

If you don't want to visit that page, you can go back to the previous page.

Comment: @LeticiaSilvaJordao That's weird. It shouldn't be doing that. You'll probably need to use something like: `href="{!$Site.BaseUrl}/{!tarefa.Id}"` instead.